# How to replace urine-soaked insulation?

Tags: insulation

How can I replace or get rid of mice-urine-soaked insulation, when the smell is strong enough to instantly make me vomit?

Comment: Get throwaway coveralls, cheap goggles, and a particulate respirator at the paint shop. Get up there and rip that stuff out and bag it and throw it away. Don't worry about replacing it right now just get the nasty stuff out of the house.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where is the insulation? In the attic? If it's a health issue, and the attic isn't yours, you may be able to get your landlord to deal with it.

Comment: I get that renting is never simple, but you need to be sure the root cause of the problem (mice) is taken care of. That's a landlord's responsibility. Depending on where you are, you might be able to tap into some free tenant support resources to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is mostly the smell. Two ways to go at it, and you may need both - a respirator with a carbon filter cartridge as well as a particulate filter cartridge (stackable), or a combination type cartridge, and a "fresh air blower" to supply clean air to the space before, during and after working in it.

---

But since I see in the bits that were (IMHO) excessively edited out of your question this is not your own home, a call to the local (health board? or whoever has jurisdiction over landlords) is where you, as a tenant, should start, (assuming that **you have already brought this to the attention of your landlord without results** - if you have not, **start there**) along with perhaps looking for a different rental and considering breaking your lease for the property not being maintained in a condition that's safe to inhabit. Ripping out the insulation is not only not your responsibility, it's also undoubtedly not something you are allowed to do, either.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how pervasive this urine issue is you may need to tear out the insulation and replace it wholesale. There may be dead mice behind the drywall, which if I'm right, is a health hazard.

You may want to look for contractors who specialize in these things.

I'm pretty sure you can do it yourself as well, but this involves a lot of work: remove drywall, remove/dispose insulation, buy/install insulation, install new drywall, repaint. You'll want to research a whole bunch of things like how to properly discard insulation and what protective gear you need to handle fiber glass.